# LDAP e AD - Erro ao adicionar usuário ao grupo com C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Estou tentando adicionar um usuário ao grupo, porém me é retornado o seguinte erro:

> Message: O servidor está relutando em processar o pedido.
>   ErrorCode: -2147016651
>   ExtendedError: 1359
>   ExtendedErrorMessage: 0000054F: SvcErr: DSID-031A120C, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
>   HResult: -2147016651

Obtenho isto com o código a seguir:

```
    public void UpdateUserGroup(ADEntry selectedEntry, ADEntry groupEntry, bool addUser)
    {
        DirectoryEntry selectedDirEntry = selectedEntry.ToDirectoryEntry(this.Connector.Credential);
        DirectoryEntry groupDirEntry = groupEntry.ToDirectoryEntry(this.Connector.Credential);

        if ((selectedDirEntry.SchemaClassName.Equals("user")) && (groupDirEntry.SchemaClassName.Equals("group")))
        {
            if (addUser)
            {
                groupDirEntry.Properties["member"].Add(selectedDirEntry.Path);
            }
            else
            {
                groupDirEntry.Properties["member"].Remove(selectedDirEntry.Path);
            }

            groupDirEntry.CommitChanges();
            groupDirEntry.RefreshCache();
        }
    }
```

O usuário que estou utilizando é DomainAdmin.
Alguém tem alguma sugestão de solução?

Grato.

Comment: Qual versão do Framework você está usando?

Comment: Estou utilizando a versão 4.5

Comment: Você está apenas mudando os grupos ou tem mais alguma alteração sendo feita? Especificamente, alteração de senha?

Answer (score 2):

Se você está na 3.5+ deveria passar a usar as classes do System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. Fica tudo muito mais simples.
Tu tem que inicializar um PrincipalContext e depois se basear nele pra fazer as operações.
Eu usava o mesmo que tu, me facilitou muito usar o novo namespace.

Não tenho o meu fonte aqui, mas acho que isso aqui já deve resolver o problema. Caso não resolva, avise:

```
public void AddUserToGroup(string userId, string groupName) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "COMPANY"))
        {
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
            group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);
            group.Save();
        }
    } 
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E) 
    { 
        //doSomething with E.Message.ToString(); 

    } 
} 

public void RemoveUserFromGroup(string userId, string groupName)
{   
    try 
    { 
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "COMPANY"))
        {
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
            group.Members.Remove(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);
            group.Save();
        }
    } 
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E) 
    { 
        //doSomething with E.Message.ToString(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Luiz, 
Antes de recorrer aos fóruns eu fiz um teste utilizando os métodos do DirectoryServices, porém o meu código da erro logo ao buscar o grupo, e o pior, com a seguinte mensagem "Erro Local.".
O usuário que estou utilizando é Domain Admin, não sei de existe alguma política que deve ser atualizada.
De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda, parece que existe muito mistério na manipulação do AD e nas mensagens de erro que a Microsoft disponibiliza.

Comment: Se dá erro logo ao buscar, acho que podes esquecer fazer alterações. Tem que ver porque ele dá esse erro. Tu diz que está usando o "Domain Admin". Precisa ser esse? Qual o tamanho do AD? Quem é responsável pelo AD? Será que não há algum tipo de bloqueio?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver utilizando o `DirectoryServices`, tive que utilizar a assinatura que fornece o usuário e a senha. No fim o método ficou assim:

```
public void UpdateUserGroup(ADEntry selectedEntry, ADEntry groupEntry, bool addUser)
{
    if (selectedEntry.Type == ADEntryType.User && groupEntry.Type == ADEntryType.Group)
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, this.Connector.Credential.Server, Connector.Credential.User, Connector.Credential.Password))
        {
            GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupEntry.Name);

            if (addUser)
            {
                group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.Name, selectedEntry.Name);                        
            }
            else
            {
                group.Members.Remove(pc, IdentityType.Name, selectedEntry.Name);
            }

            group.Save();
        }
    }            
}
```

Obrigado Luiz [pela ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16852/ldap-e-ad-erro-ao-adicionar-usuario-ao-grupo-com-c/17229#17229).

Comment: Isto eu sei, mas não tinha pontos suficientes no stack pt para votar.

Comment: Já tenho e já votei